# Is thermal imaging possible with a Raspberry Pi Camera with Night Vision and IR Sensor Light?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

We just set up this [Raspberry Pi Camera with Night Vision and IR Sensor Light](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-3-Camera-Focal-Adjustable-Night-Vision-Camera-Holder-IR-Sensor-Light-FFC-for-RPI/32848614746.html) to stream video.

I'm trying to understand what this camera actually captures, and if it's possible to do thermal imaging with it and what I'd need to do that. What's it doing exactly? It looks like it's capturing a mix of IR and RGB, is this right? How do I process the video image to get a thermal image and analyze the data? Are there any good code libraries available for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this camera doesn't do thermal imaging. It simply allows the sensor of the camera to receive infrared light. It's easy to mistake this as a thermal camera as people associate the 'infrared' with heat. Sadly, not the case.

The part of the spectrum of light that is just beyond the visible spectrum in the red direction is referred to as infrared. It's pretty much invisible to our eyes, but the sensors on most cameras can usually receive it well. So well, that most cameras have a filter in them to block infrared light from hitting the sensor. In the case of the camera you've linked to, this does **not** filter out the infrared light, so you will see that part of the light spectrum. To make the process easier, there are a couple of infrared emitting leds attached. So while it says 'Night Vision' that means that it will show you an image in what appears to be a pitch black scene, but that can only happen because it is illuminating the scene with light emitted by the infrared leds.

You can demonstrate the ability of cameras to see infrared well by getting a camera (like your phone) and pointing a remote control at it while you're pressing a button. You should see the light from the remote control come on in the camera, but not with the naked eye.

Answer (score 2):

'Thermal imaging' is a rather broad term. If you take a color photo of a glowing iron bar, you can be argued to do thermal imaging.

As  a wild guess I'll say that you would like to do thermal imaging of humans. This involves detecting wavelengths emitted by something at a temperature on the order of 300K. Look at a blackbody radiation chart to figure out the wavelength (around 10 micrometers = 10 000nm)

To figure out what Temperature emits lots of the wavelength that a Pi-night vision camera detects (around 900nm), also consult the chart. E.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Note: As you can see while heating a bar of iron up slowly, at lesser temperatures there is only a red glow, that slowly shifts to a bright yellowish white. This exemplifies the process you can also see on the chart: Hotter bodies emit every wavelength a colder body does, and more of them, plus more short length wavelengths (in the visible that's more blue). Thus you need the ratio of at least two wavelengths to decide at what temperature something is emitting.

Note2: Transparency is a feature that only holds true at certain wavelengths: Glass for instance is not transparent at the wavelengths of human body warmth, thus you cannot use normal (glass) optics for thermal imaging. Water vapor on the other hand is more transparent at the 900nm that your night vision camera is working at, thus you can see through fog better.